# Perceptron Algorithm Implementation in Deep Learning for Computer Vision with Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am working with the book [Deep Learning for Computer Vision with Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/deep-learning-computer-vision-python-book/) by Adrian Rosebrock. I am wondering why the results in scikit-learn is significantly different from the one implemented in the book. Please check the code [here.](https://github.com/benjcabalona1029/Issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#perceptron):

> The Perceptron is another simple classification algorithm suitable for
>   large scale learning. By default:
>
> - It does not require a learning rate.
> - It is not regularized (penalized).
> - It updates its model only on mistakes.
>
> The last characteristic implies that the Perceptron is slightly faster
>   to train than SGD with the hinge loss and that the resulting models
>   are sparser.

And from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html#sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron)

> Perceptron is a classification algorithm which shares the same
>   underlying implementation with SGDClassifier. In fact, Perceptron() is
>   equivalent to `SGDClassifier(loss="perceptron", eta0=1,
>   learning_rate="constant", penalty=None)`

So you should compare results with `SGDClassifier` by specifying the same parameters - loss function, learning rate, regularisation, random state, shuffle and etc.